# Declaring variables before or after an early return?

Tags: javascript

In some JavaScript functions or classes you'd usually see variables declared at the top of that function:

```
function someThing(foobar) {
  const qux = 123;

  if (!foobar) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

But in the case where you'd use an early return, is it a common pattern to define the constants after the early return?

```
function someThing(foobar) {
  if (!foobar) {
    return false;
  }

  // foobar is defined, so let's do something:
  const qux = 123;
  return qux;
}
```

That way it doesn't assign the variable if it does not have to.

But on the other hand having variables at the top and not scattered across the function would make it more readable.

Is there a pattern for this situation?

Comment: avoiding any computation / assignment etc where possible would be a good idea, yes.  Its personal preference on it being more readable too, I prefer related code to be near to each other, I would argue that all the vars at the top of the function would be _less_ readable, and slightly harder to extract / refactor when needed.

Comment: This would be opinion based. So, here is my opinion - if you have an early exit, then don't declare anything before it that's not used as part of the early exit. Only have what's worth reading. No need to declare 5 variables only to discard them on the next line with a `return;`. Declare them when you need to use them. Also, don't declare *all* possible variables if you aren't going to use all. This is a very outdated writing style that didn't have much reason to exist before but certainly not nowadays.

Comment: Not ideal that this is closed as "opinion based". If it's something commonly used than it can be a design pattern which is what I'm looking for.

Comment: *I* often do this, as it avoids evaluating the initializer of the variable when it isn't necessary, and *I* think, that it can be done in a way, that *I* find readable. However, as my sentence includes ***I***, this is opinion-based, as it was *my opinion* about it.

Comment: @Remi that's nothing to do with design patterns.

Comment: I'm afraid this question is opinion-based, indeed. As of my opinion, I totally agree with the other two commenters. So (1) handle early-return immediately (without anything in front); and (2) keep variables close at where they are used.

Comment: You're right. More a code style guide.

Comment: Be careful with assumptions about variable declaration in Javascript if you do not understand the concept of [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting).